# Does iphone provide any API to detect human thumb Impression?

Tags: iphone, signature, scanning

I wish to develop an app in iPhone in which user's thumb will be scanned first. The impression of the thumb should be used as a signature for email or report.
Please suggest if its possible to do or not. If its possible then are there any tutorials or link.

Thanks in advance,
Prerna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, iPhone detects touches as points, it's not sensitive enough to detect the  human thumb with the fine marks of a thumbprint.

Many have tried, some may even provide code, but ultimately it can't work.