# How to take thumb impression in android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does iphone provide any API to detect human thumb Impression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752859/does-iphone-provide-any-api-to-detect-human-thumb-impression)
>   [Is fingerprint supported in android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369799/is-fingerprint-supported-in-android-devices)

every one.
i want to take thumb impression in my android phone by using pressing on mobile screen.
is there any API for thumb impression.?

Comment: if you want to use the screen for that then no, you can't.

Comment: by touching the screen on phone..

Comment: We haven't got _those_ screens yet :)

Comment: see this i want this type of apps.. http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/thumb+impression

Comment: how can they developed...?
please any on can tell me how to develop that type of apps in android.

Answer (score 0):

Thumb impressions used to scan for fingerprints require specialized devices/components that are not part of standard android cell phone screens.

Hence, there is no API and this functionality is not supported by android at this time.